# Transformation of two ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, arraylist

I've got a couple of ArrayList:

ArrayList a --> ["52", "52", "52", "52", "67", "67", "67", "67"]

ArrayList b --> ["1", "4", "5", "6", "3", "4", "5", "10"]

I want to transform them into:

ArrayList at --> ["52", "52", "67", "67"]

ArrayList bt --> ["1", "4 - 6", "3 - 5", "10"]

I know how to make b into bt, but I can't wrap my head around making a into at.

Algorith for making b into bt:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> alist = new ArrayList<String>();
    alist.add("1");
    alist.add("4");
    alist.add("5");
    alist.add("6");
    alist.add("3");
    alist.add("4");
    alist.add("5");       
    alist.add("10");

    alist = groupByRange(alist);

}

static public ArrayList<String> groupByRange(ArrayList<String> alist) {

    // ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<Integer>
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ArrayList<Integer> alist_int = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (String ident : alist) {
        alist_int.add(Integer.parseInt(ident));
    }

    // ArrayList<Integer> to int[]
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    int[] arr = new int[alist_int.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = alist_int.get(i);
    }

    // Grouping by range (return ArrayList<String>)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    int start, end;
    end = start = arr[0];
    ArrayList<String> alist_res = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == (arr[i - 1] + 1)) {
            end = arr[i];
        } else {

            if (start == end) {
                alist_res.add(String.valueOf(start));
            } else {
                alist_res.add(String.valueOf(start) + " - " + String.valueOf(end));
            }
            start = end = arr[i];
        }
    }

    if (start == end) {
        alist_res.add(String.valueOf(start));
    } else {
        alist_res.add(String.valueOf(start) + " - " + String.valueOf(end));
    }

    for (String n : alist_res) {
        System.out.println(n);
    }

    return alist_res;
}
```

Comment: The thing is: in order to code anything, you first need **clarity** about your requirements. For example: what is the rule that tells you that (52,52,52,52) should be reduced to (52,52)? Does the rule say: only two times the same number in a row? Or: reduce duplicates to only two occurrences?  What I mean is: you first need to **clearly** specify the **rules** for your transformations. And then you start thinking about the "how". Implementing unclear rules can only lead to confusion and misery.

Comment: Then please EDIT your question; dont start putting stuff into comments!

Comment: I hoped it was clear in my example, but you are kinda right. I'll try to explain: 52 is asociated with 1, 4, 5 and 6; the same as 67 is associated with 3, 4, 5 and 10. That's why I need (52) --> (1), (52) --> (4-6), (67) --> (3-5) and (67) --> (10)

Comment: What about `a=[52,52,52,67,67,67,67,67}, b={1,4,5,6,3,4,5,10}` you have the range of 4..6 spanning over 52,52,67, how do you deal with this?

Comment: The result should be: at = [52, 52, 67, 67, 67] and bt = [1, 4-5, 6, 3-5, 10

Answer (score 0):

I have method for You:

```
   public List<String> groupByValue(List<String> listA) {

    if (listA.isEmpty()) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(listA.get(0));

    for (int actualIndex = 1; actualIndex < listA.size(); actualIndex++) {
        if (actualIndex + 1 < listA.size() - 1 && !listA.get(actualIndex + 1).equals(listA.get(actualIndex))) {
            result.add(listA.get(actualIndex));
            actualIndex++;
        }
        if (actualIndex < listA.size() - 1 && !listA.get(actualIndex - 1).equals(listA.get(actualIndex))) {
            result.add(listA.get(actualIndex));
        }
        if (actualIndex + 1 == listA.size()) {
            result.add(listA.get(actualIndex));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

This method has one parameter, is Your input list a. Then, we chcek list, and next, we add first value from a list. Next we check next values, and we have result on the end, it means at list.

Comment: It doesn't work. The method should have 2 parameters (a and b), because the size of the array bt is equals to at. I've tested it and it won't work like this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, maybe you can give as more details about how this method should work? more about parameters? More about specification ?

Comment: I don't think that's necessary. The problem is simple, but I'm afraid I didn't make it very clear. Sorry about that. I'll edit the main post soon enough.